# Scope in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have controller where I have the following code:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderByDesc('id')->paginate(15);
    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

This return all posts in a page. On the page I have tabs: `all posts`, `posts by time`, `posts by rating`.

In model I have this scope:

```
public function scopeOfType($query, $type)
{
    return $query->where('type', $status);
}
```

How I can call this on the page where I have the tabs?

When I try call scope with:

```
@forelse($posts->ofType($type) as $post)
```

I get error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::ofType does not exist. (View:
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: scopes are only query builder shortcuts so `Post::orderByDesc('id')->ofType($type)->paginate(15)` would work, but after you do the paginate you have the model collection and not the query builder

Comment: You cannot use scopes in view like that. You can however call the model directly in the page, even though it's not recommended. @foreach(\Post::orderByDesc('id')->ofType($type)->limit(15)->get() as $value) ..... Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: And how then I can get `$type` in controller from blade without request and ajax?

Comment: @Dumitru return an array with data for each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop by type as you stated, you could use where on the collection already:

```
@forelse($posts->where('type', $type) as $post)
```

Note this is a collection and it filters it by the type you gave.